# Wolfram Alpha error?

Tags: computational-mathematics

I was seeing some equations in WA, and i got with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28k%2B1%29%5E2%3E%3D4%28k-1%29%5E2

Let's manually solve the equation
$$(k+1)^2\ge4(k-1)^2$$
$$(k+1)^2-(2k-2)^2\ge0$$
$$(-k+3)(3k-1)\ge0$$
But in alternate forms, it gives
$$(k-3)\left(k-\frac13\right)\ge0$$
What is happening here?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's a bug. Somebody should report it.

Comment: @DanielFischer How do you do that?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe there's something on the "about" page or so, maybe one can only report a bug with an account, but perhaps someone on Mathematica.se knows.

Comment: @DanielFischer I sent an email to their "support" mail. I guess that is the best I can do for now.

Comment: That should do, methinks. Well done, and good find.

Comment: WolframAlpha bugs can be reported via the "Give us your feedback" window at the bottom of the page.  This is nice since the input and result you received are automatically included.

Comment: @MarkMcClure thank you, now I also reported it from there to have more chance of success.

Comment: Your last step is wrong. If you multiply (-k+3)(3k-1)>=0 with -1/3 then sign of inequality will change. It will be (k-3)(k-1/3)<=0 instead of ">=0".

Comment: @Mathematician171 There is no step between the third and fourth line, the fourth was(the error has been fixed) WA's bogus reult :)

Comment: I checked the site just now and the inequality is in the correct direction (i.e. reversed from the original). To be more explicit, the site is now listing $(k-3)(k - \frac 13) \leq 0$ as one of the alternate forms, which *is* correct. Has the bug been fixed? I assume there was no typo in the original question?

Comment: @Deepak Yes, it has been fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an error.  I have reported it, and received this message back from WolframAlpha:

> We appreciate your feedback regarding Wolfram|Alpha. Your suggestion has been passed along to our development team for review. 
>   Thank you for helping us improve Wolfram|Alpha. 
>   Best wishes,
>   The Wolfram|Alpha Team
>   www.wolframalpha.com

Comment: Thank you, I have received that message 1 hour ago too.Let's see when it gets fixed :)