# closed form sum: $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2^{-i}}{i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across this gnarly sum and was wondering if anyone knew any tricks to get a closed form for it:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2^{-i}}{i}$$

Comment: You'd have to use special functions like Lerch Transcendents.

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 2):

As said by Batman in his comment, this summation involves Lerch transcendent function and simply write $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2^{-i}}{i}=\log (2)-2^{-(n+1)} \Phi \left(\frac{1}{2},1,n+1\right)$$ For $n$ going to infinity, the limit is $\log (2)$.

Also as mentioned by Apurv, for large values of $n$ this summation looks like the infinite Taylor series of $$-\log (1-x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^6}{6}+\frac{x^7}{7}
   +\frac{x^8}{8}+O\left(x^9\right)$$ If you plug $x=\frac{1}{2}$, you end with a limit equal to $-\log \frac{1}{2}= \log (2)$.

Comment: I can see someone having this as a homework problem, coming across this page and then sending their TA "Batman said it can't be done."

Comment: @AsafKaragila. This is not tagged as $homework$.

Comment: I never said this is. It is a very hypothetical scenario.

Comment: May be I kept it ! Is it because the name of the user who commented (Batman) ? I admit this could be funny. Then +1 for the humor. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A closed form of the sum does not exist. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation+%282%5E-r%29%2Fr+from+1+to+n).

However, you can find the limit of the sum as n tends to infinity, using [Taylor series for $\log (1+x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+series+for+log%281%2Bx%29) and then putting $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: WolframAlpha is a good source of pointers to reverse-engineer the answer, but it is not a source for an answer. I have seen Wolfram fail, personally, with may own eyes(and several others). See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465387/wolfram-alpha-error)